# How to access tab bar controller in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In Xcode 4.2, I created a new project from the "tabbed application" template. Now I want to access the tab bar controller in the AppDelegate, but this property is missing. How to solve the problem.

In previous version of Xcode, I can access it by calling the self.tabBarController, however, I could not do that in iOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magic happening with the `tabBarController` property that appears in "tabbed application" template projects. I guess pre-iOS 5 the template was designed so that the tab controller was already set up as an attached outlet for you. If it's not in the template you're using then you just need to add the property yourself. Below are instructions on how to do this.

You just need to add a property for it and then grab the `rootViewController` from your `UIWindow` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. i.e. you want something like this in your app delegate header:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
...
@end
```

Then synthesise it in your app delegate implementation and grab it from `rootViewController`:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: you have to initialize UITabBarDelegate method @interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject<UITabBardelegate>

Comment: You don't *have* to do that. Only if you want to be its delegate.

Comment: @mattjgalloway, in iOS 5 & Xcode 4.2, I could not find MainWindow.xib and I am using storyboard. Are you using Xcode 4.2?

Comment: I do use 4.2 yes. If you are using a storyboard then hook it up from your main storyboard file then.

Comment: @user403015 - OK I've edited it slightly so that it might be a bit easier for you now.

Comment: How to connect the UITabBarController to the storyboard? Would you please tell me the steps in details. Thanks.

Comment: @user403015 Read my updated answer. Nothing to do with the storyboard. Just add that code into your app delegate. This is assuming you've gone straight from the tabbed application template. I did this earlier today and tested that my method works so if it's not for you then please post more code so we can see more context.

Comment: @user403015 Any more questions on this or are you just going to leave our 2 answers down voted even though we're helping as much as possible with very little information given?

Answer (score 1):

if u're using 4.2, i'm pretty sure that on the appDelegate, its automatically added

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

u can access it on the implementation file by using the method u've been using, self.tabBarController

just make sure that it's properly synthesized on the implementation file and u write the code in the proper method body

im sorry but im not very clear of what your problem is

Comment: I am using storyboard, there is no property of the UITabBarController.

Comment: then, you could easily add the property as written above in the header file, at least when you don't really know what you're doing, don't down voted answer you're not clear of, it shows your lack of respect of other